# How to get a forward moving average using the Bottleneck package?

Tags: python, moving-average, bottleneck-package

Using the Bottleneck package, I'm able to do a backward-moving average of my data, but I'm unable to find how to do the **forward** moving average. The below code is for the **backward** moving average:

```
import bottleneck as bn
bn.move_mean(data, window=4, min_count=1)
```

Is there a way to do the **forward** moving average using the Bottleneck library?

Comment: What would be the difference between forward and backward apart from an index offset which you can very easily implement?

Comment: The only difference is the index offset. @Julien

Comment: Then just offset your index? How is that difficult?

Comment: You could try to reverse your data by calling the list utility ``reversed(data)`` and than call your forward moving average